# SSIS DataFlow slows down considerably over time

Tags: .net, sql, database, sql-server-2008, ssis

I've got an ADO NET Source component which queries a table for all of it's 700,000 records.

This is connected to a SQL Server Destination component.

it takes 23 seconds (+ - 1 second) to process the first 100,000 records.

The next 100,000 records take an additional 50 seconds.  And it only gets worse.

Below are the specifics and details

---

I've already tried the following three different commands on the destination database.

```
ALTER DATABASE AdamDB SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

ALTER DATABASE AdamDB SET RECOVERY BULK_LOGGED ;

ALTER DATABASE AdamDB SET RECOVERY FULL ;
```

In all 3 cases, the time remained at 23 seconds for the first 100,000 records.

---

I've also tried putting in a Conditional Split component based on the ID value

```
Default
SKU % 4 < 1
SKU % 4 < 2
SKU % 4 < 3
```

Each output condition has a different SQL Server Destination, and I've even gone so far as to create a different Connection Manager for each destination.

[image: Conditional Split]

---

None of this seems to have had any noticeable affect on performance.

**Here is the Source Connection Manager**

[image: Source Connection Manager]

**Here are my source object properties.**

[image: Source Object Properties]

**And here is the connection manager for the destination**

[image: Destination Connection Manager]

**and here are my destination object properties.**

[image: Destination Connection Properties]

---

---

How can I speed this up?

**edit**

From Lamak's suggestion, I've tried using an OLE DB Destination instead of a SQL Server Destination.  This seems to have the same speed result and slowdown over time.

Comment: Did you try using the "Ole DB Destination" instead?. You can choose "Table or view - fast load" on the "Data access mode" to speed the loading.

Comment: @Lamak Have not, I'll work on that right now to see.

Comment: Let me know how it goes. And you need to take into account that "Fast load" takes some locks on the table in order to insert rows faster

Comment: @Lamak Same speed unfortunately.  Tried it with 1 OLE DB Destination and also with 4.  Used the "Table or view - fast load" access mode.  Rows per batch: [left blank]

Comment: Do you need the conditional split?, can you load everything to one table and then split the results?. How fast is the source reading the rows?, is the driver the right one?

Comment: @Lamak I don't need the split, just found it as a speed suggestion, tried without and have same speed results.  Not sure how to tell the speed of the reader, or the "right" driver.

Comment: What is the source database provider?

Comment: @Lamak it's an iSeries DB2 database.  Here is the ConnectionManagerType if thats what you're looking for  --- --- ADO.NET:IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries.iDB2Connection, IBM.Data.DB2.iSeries, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9cdb2ebfb1f93a26  ---  ---  I'll update my OP with screenshots

Comment: @Lamak I think I've got seomthing.  I changed the source connection manager's block size from 0(default) to 5,000.   Doesn't seem to be slowing down now for some reason, speeding right along!!!

Comment: Good, you could've also tried changing the provider to use the native Ole DB provider for DB2. (you can find a link here: http://www.bidn.com/blogs/PatrickLeBlanc/ssis/700/connecting-to-db2-using-ssis)

Comment: Do you write in batches? (100k at once?) Or you're just counting the first 100k, second 100k,...etc.

Comment: @Marian I have no idea, I didn't set any configuration that specifies one or another.  Not even sure what the "block size" change does, yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who may run into the same situation... it was a simple fix, after some very guided & helpful comments!

I ended up using an OLE DB Source and OLE DB Destination object instead of ADO objects.

Usage on just the destination, while the source remains ADO still gives slow results.

Usage of OLE DB on both source and destination fixed the issue.

I am now processing 750,000 records in about 55 seconds total!